# Prevent `floatingfigure` start a new paragraph

Tags: floats, environments, paragraphs

Let's say I have a custom environment called `solution`:

```
\documentclass[paper = B5]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\NewDocumentCommand\sparsetext{m}{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace = 30}#1}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{+b}{%
    \par\footnotesize\sparsetext{Solution}. #1%
}{\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{solution}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Here is what the above typesets:
[image]

I can't keep it in one paragraph, if I insert a picture:

```
\documentclass[paper = B5]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\NewDocumentCommand\sparsetext{m}{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace = 30}#1}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{+b}{%
    \par\footnotesize\sparsetext{Solution}. #1%
}{\par}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\afig}
\begin{lrbox}{\afig}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) circle [radius = 1];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{solution}%
    \begin{floatingfigure}[p]{\wd\afig}%
        \noindent\usebox{\afig}%
    \end{floatingfigure}%
    \lipsum[1]
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

How can I keep the text in one paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{floatingfigure}` can't be used in the middle of a paragraph but has to be used before the paragraph where it should be active. This can't be changed easily since `floatflt` has to insert a trial paragraph to determine if the figure fits on the current page. But since your paragraph starts inside of the `\begin{solution}` code, you can just move the figure before that:

```latex
\documentclass[paper = B5]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\NewDocumentCommand\sparsetext{m}{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace = 30}#1}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{solution}{}{%
    \par\footnotesize\sparsetext{Solution}.
}{\par}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\afig}
\begin{lrbox}{\afig}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) circle [radius = 1];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{floatingfigure}[p]{\wd\afig}%
    \noindent\usebox{\afig}%
\end{floatingfigure}%
\begin{solution}%
    \lipsum[1]
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's a workaround, but I see that there are no other options. The only thing that MS Word is better than LaTeX is how the former works with floating pictures.